# Is there any library for binary Search in C++

Tags: c++, search

Is there any pre-implemented library in C++ for fast search in a list like binary search? Does the normal list support any kind of find function? Or any function like exists?

I have a list of objects, I want to store them in a list, but not duplicate elements. I want to notice whether or not the new element exists in the list and do a proper action.

Comment: Are you sure that binary searching a **list** is going to be a good idea?

Comment: What prevented you from reading the information about C++ standard containers and algorithms in your favourite C++ standard library reference? It would only take half a day to become familiar with the options available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Container list is not adopted for ordering storing of elements and for their direct access. Though standard class `std::list` has member functions `sort` nevertheless the search using bidirectional iterators (`std::list`has bidirectional iterators) instead of random access iterators is not very effective..

It would be better if you would use some associative container as for example `std::map` or `std::set` (if you need unique elements) or `std::multimap` or `std::multiset` (if elements can be duplucated).

if the order of elements is not important then you could use some standard unordered container as `std::unordered_map` or `std::unordered_set`

Comment: If I use set for instance, it gives me any warning that the new element exists before or not? I can look at the size of set after each  insertion to see any change to notice whether the last element exists before or not. Do you think this is a good idea?

Comment: @user2373198 With std:;set you can use such its member functions as find (it applies the binary search), lower_bound, upper_bound and count. For example if count will return 0 then it means that there is no an element with the key in the set.

Comment: yes it works, thank you. I don't have enough reputation to like your comment.

Comment: @user2373198 You can mark my answer as the most useful.:)

Answer (score 3):

There is `std::lower_bound()` which finds a suitable position in any bidirectional sequence using `O(log n)` comparisons. Since linked lists don't support random access traversal is `O(n)`. You can use `std::binary_search()` if you are only interested whether there is a suitable object but this algorithm isn't useful if you are interested in locating the object. Of course, a precondition for `std::lower_bound()` and `std::binary_search()` is that the sequence is sorted.

Comment: I have a list of objects, I want to store them in a list, but not duplicate elements. I want to notice whether or not the new element exists in the list and do a proper action. do you think is there any better option to store element for this purpose? for example since I don't know the whole number of element I don't want to use array.

Comment: @user2373198: well, all the information is in my answer: how to find the location using standard algorithms, what the constraints, and complexities are.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for the C++ [`<algorithm>` library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/). It includes a function called [`binary_search`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/).

An example of it is provided on the page and echoed here:

```
// binary_search example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::binary_search, std::sort
#include <vector>       // std::vector

bool myfunction (int i,int j) { return (i<j); }

int main () {
  int myints[] = {1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1};
  std::vector<int> v(myints,myints+9);                         // 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1

  // using default comparison:
  std::sort (v.begin(), v.end());

  std::cout << "looking for a 3... ";
  if (std::binary_search (v.begin(), v.end(), 3))
    std::cout << "found!\n"; else std::cout << "not found.\n";

  // using myfunction as comp:
  std::sort (v.begin(), v.end(), myfunction);

  std::cout << "looking for a 6... ";
  if (std::binary_search (v.begin(), v.end(), 6, myfunction))
    std::cout << "found!\n"; else std::cout << "not found.\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: See also `std::equal_range`, `std::lower_bound` or `std::upper_bound`. These might be more useful than `std::binary_search`, if you actually want to find and *use* an element.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing real C++ code you can use the algorithm standard library.

In it there is the [find function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) which grant to you to look for a specific element defined between a range of element specified as a parameter.

You can find a real example in the same page.

Comment: I have a list of objects, I want to store them in a list, but not duplicate elements. I want to notice whether or not the new element exists in the list and do a proper action. for example in c# it can easily achievable by exist method which all list has it.

Comment: If you don't want to have duplicates you need a set. This will grant to you to easilybuse binary search because it is already sorted.